# .NET Attributes List

Tags: .net, attributes

Is there a list somewhere on common Attributes which are used in objects like `Serializable`?

Thanks

Edit ~ The reason I asked is that I came across an StoredProcedure attribute in ntiers ORMS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, look msdn has you covered please look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx#inheritanceContinued).

EDIT: This link only answer sucked. Here is a working extractor for all loadable types (gac) that have Attribute in the name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var process = new Process();
            //your path may vary
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\gacutil.exe";
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/l";
            process.Start();

            var consoleOutput = process.StandardOutput;


            var assemblyList = new List<string>();
            var startAdding = false;
            while (consoleOutput.EndOfStream == false)
            {
                var line = consoleOutput.ReadLine();
                if (line.IndexOf("The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    startAdding = true;
                    continue;
                }

                if (startAdding == false)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                //add any other filter conditions (framework version, etc)
                if (line.IndexOf("System.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                assemblyList.Add(line.Trim());
            }

            var collectedRecords = new List<string>();
            var failedToLoad = new List<string>();

            Console.WriteLine($"Found {assemblyList.Count} assemblies");
            var currentItem = 1;


            foreach (var gacAssemblyInfo in assemblyList)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                Console.WriteLine($"On {currentItem} of {assemblyList.Count} ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 3);
                Console.WriteLine($"Loading {gacAssemblyInfo}");
                currentItem++;

                try
                {
                    var asm = Assembly.Load(gacAssemblyInfo);

                    foreach (Type t in asm.GetTypes())
                    {
                        if (t.Name.EndsWith("Attribute", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            collectedRecords.Add($"{t.FullName} - {t.Assembly.FullName}");
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    failedToLoad.Add($"FAILED to load {gacAssemblyInfo} - {ex}");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 9);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failure to load count: {failedToLoad.Count}");
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(4, 10);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Last Fail: {gacAssemblyInfo}");
                }
            }

            var fileBase = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
            var goodFile = $"{fileBase}_good.txt";
            var failFile = $"{fileBase}_failedToLoad.txt";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(goodFile, collectedRecords);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(failFile, failedToLoad);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 15);
            Console.WriteLine($"Matching types: {goodFile}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Failures: {failFile}");
            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All I saw was "Attributes which are used in objects like ?" - The post   had been stripped of its serializable attribute. I though he was asking about nullables (? and ??)

Comment: removed comments and updated answer to have accurate information once misunderstanding was cleared up

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, you can create your own attributes. If you are searching through someone else's code, it's easy to get confused when they create their own.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a complete list of Attributes, but a search for Attribute in MSDN can yield interesting results. I have tended to browse namespaces for interesting attribute types and then go look them up to see what I might use them for. Not the most efficient approach, I know.

The MSDN entry for [System.Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx) has a list at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You may not find what you're looking for because it's possible that you're looking at a custom attribute.

http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0307041

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflector to browse the `mscorlib` assembly, and under **`System.Attribute`**, expand the *Derived Types* node. It will show all attributes for all the assemblies currently loaded in Reflector.